# Get the ID of the selected item in Dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

I have to save the ID of a selected item into the database. but, I always get a null value when I select an item from the dropdown.

Here is some code:
Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        SelectList CategoryList = new SelectList(dc.Category.ToList(), "ID", "CategoryName");
        ViewData["Categories"] = CategoryList;
        ViewData.Model = new AdvertModel();
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
<%:Html.DropDownList("Categories", ViewData["Categories"] as SelectList, new { @class = "dropdown" })%>
```

MODEL: AdvertModel

```
public class AdvertModel
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false,ErrorMessage="Please enter the title of your Ad.")]
    [Display(Name="Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false,ErrorMessage="Please enter a description of your Ad.")]
    [Display(Name = "Details")]
    public string Details { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false,ErrorMessage="Please enter when your Ad. will be publish")]
    [Display(Name = "Publish date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime PubDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }

    public bool AdStatus { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public Category Category { get; set; }

}
```

And now I want to get the ID of the selected item:

```
public ActionResult Create(AdvertModel ad)
    {
        Advert nAD = new Advert();
        nAD.Title = ad.Title;
        nAD.Message = ad.Details;
        nAD.PublishDate = ad.PubDate;

        nAD.Category = ad.Category.ID;// here I always get null. 

        dc.Advert.AddObject(nAD);
        dc.SaveChanges();

        return View(ad);
    }
```

Any idea where am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of The `Html.DropDownList` is the HTML Id.

Add a `CategoryId` to your ViewModel and change your Dropdown List to:

```
<%:Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", ViewData["Categories"] as SelectList, new { @class = "dropdown" })%>
```

Or this might work with your current code (but not tested):

```
<%:Html.DropDownList("Category_ID", ViewData["Categories"] as SelectList, new { @class = "dropdown" })%>
```

Comment: Asp.Net MVC translates Category.ID to Category_ID ... give it a try

Comment: Add the `CategoryId` to your viewModel, and try the DropDownList with the first variable as `CategoryId` ... that should work.  Then set your Category.ID = CategoryId